# Prove one of these linear transformations doesn't exist

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

I recently came across this problem:

> Let $V$ and $W$ be the subspaces
> $$V=\mathrm{Lin}\left\{\left(\begin{array}{r} 1\\ 0\\ -1\end{array}\right),\left(\begin{array}{r} 1\\ -1\\ 0\end{array}\right)\right\}\subset\mathbb{R}^3,$$
> $$W=\mathrm{Lin}\left\{\left(\begin{array}{r} 1\\ 3\\ 1\\0 \end{array}\right),\left(\begin{array}{r} -2\\ 5\\ 0\\ 1\end{array}\right)\right\}\subset\mathbb{R}^4.$$
> Consider the possibility of a linear transformation $T$ and a linear transformation $S$ such that
> $$T:\mathbb{R}^a\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^b\ \text{with}\ N(T)=V\ \text{and}\ R(T)=W;$$
> $$S:\mathbb{R}^c\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^d\ \text{with}\ N(S)=W\ \text{and}\ R(S)=V.$$
> Show that one of these, $S$ or $T$, cannot exists. Then find a matrix $A_S$ or $A_T$ representing the other linear transformation (with respect to the standard basis in each Euclidean space).
>
> Check you answer by row reducing the matrix and finding the null space and range of the linear transformation.

And can't find an actual solution.

$A_T$ must be a $b\times a$ matrix since for some $x_{a\times 1}$ we have $A_T{_{b\times a}}x_{a\times1} = [x]_T{_{b\times1}}$. Then I applied the same reasoning on $S$. $A_S$ must be a $d\times c$ matrix since for some $x$ that is $c\times 1$ we have $A_S{_{d\times c}}x_{c\times1} = [x]_S{_{d\times1}}$. I thought of using the rank-nullity theorem to find $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$.

$\dim(N(T)) + \dim(R(T)) = \dim(R^{a}) \implies 2 + 2 = a \implies a = 4$, so $A_T{_{b\times4}}$ and
$\dim(N(S)) + \dim(R(S)) = \dim(R^{c}) \implies 2 + 2 = c \implies c = 4$, so $A_S{_{d\times4}}$

but I can't think of more operations to prove that $S$ and $T$ can't coexist.

Comment: Welcome to MSE, and nice first try using $\LaTeX$. The product $\times$ is typesetted as ```\times```. Also, $\dim(T)$ is meaningless: dimension can be only used to describe the size of basis of a *subspace*. It should be $\dim(\mathbb{R}^a)$.

Comment: And in fact, you don't (and shouldn't) need rank-nullity to decide $a,b,c$ and $d$. Just look at what should be the domain and codomain of $T$ and $S$, and try deduce a contradiction using rank-nullity.

Comment: Thank you for the warm welcome @macton. I'm glad to be here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Theorem.** If $T\in\mathcal{L}(V_1,V_2)$ and $V_1$ is finite-dimensional then $\dim V_1=\dim(N(T))+\dim(R(T))$.

Clearly $\dim V=\dim W=2$. If $N(T)=V$ then $V\subset\mathbb{R}^a$ so $a=3$. If that were the case, we would have
$$3=\dim\mathbb{R}^3=\dim N(T)+\dim R(T)=2+2=4,$$
which is not possible. Then, no such $T$ can exists.

So $S$ exists, and by the argument above must be $S:\mathbb{R}^4\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^3$. For constructing such $S$, you can choose two more (independent) vectors to complete a basis for $\mathbb{R}^4$. For example:
$$\mathcal{B}=\left\{\left(\begin{array}{r} 1\\ 0\\ 0\\ 0\end{array}\right),\left(\begin{array}{r} 0\\ 1\\ 0\\ 0\end{array}\right),\left(\begin{array}{r} 1\\ 3\\ 1\\0 \end{array}\right),\left(\begin{array}{r} -2\\ 5\\ 0\\ 1\end{array}\right)\right\}.$$
And you can set
$$S\left(\begin{array}{r} 1\\ 0\\ 0\\ 0\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{r} 1\\ 0\\ -1\end{array}\right),\ S\left(\begin{array}{r} 0\\ 1\\ 0\\ 0\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{r} 1\\ -1\\ 0\end{array}\right),\ S\left(\begin{array}{r} 1\\ 3\\ 1\\0\end{array}\right)=S\left(\begin{array}{r} -2\\ 5\\ 0\\ 1\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{r} 0\\ 0\\ 0\end{array}\right).$$
Now you have the desired $S$, but you need to apply a change of basis which I left for you.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer.I followed your solution until you stated $S:\mathbb{R}^4\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^3$. Then I followed a method I find easier to use and remember, but I am not sure whether what I did was correct, so I'd like a quick review if possible. From the range of $S$ I know the first 2 colons of $S_4 \times 3$, but 2 others are noted with variables. I can multiply this matrix by $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 3 & 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}^T$ and get $0$ (same for $\begin{bmatrix}-2 & 5 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}^T$, since these vectors are part of $N(S)$). This way I can find the unknown variables.

Comment: Also I'd like to say many thanks, but the previous comment was pretty long to keep this sentence.

Comment: Yes, I think your method will work fine too